# How to access node_modules with django compressor?

Tags: python, node.js, django, node-modules

I'm using the [Django compressor](https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor) package. However I don't know the best way to access files from node_modules.

For example I installed the following modules vie npm:

```
"clipboard": "^2.0.1",
"flatpickr": "^4.5.0",
"highlightjs": "^9.12.0",
"jquery": "^3.3.1",
```

I don't think it's a good idea to put my node_modules folder in the static directory.

How should I access the files from the node modules?